# How to fix threading bug

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

The following code on the set of each pictureBox_right and pictureBox_left gives me an error that the object is in use elsewhere. I was wondering how do i fix this.

```
private Bitmap pictureBox_right
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObject)
                return (Bitmap)this.pictureBox_rightConnectivity.Image.DeepClone();
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                pictureBox_rightConnectivity.Image = value.DeepClone();
            }
        }
    }
    private Bitmap pictureBox_left
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObject)
                return (Bitmap)this.pictureBox_leftConnectivity.Image.DeepClone();
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                this.pictureBox_leftConnectivity.Image = value.DeepClone();
            }
        }
    }
```

Following are the lines of code that cause the error:

```
  Bitmap copy;
                lock (ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button)
                {
                    copy = new Bitmap(ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button);
                    pictureBox_rightConnectivity.Image = new Bitmap(ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button);
                    //pictureBox_right = ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button;

                }

                    pictureBox_right = copy;
```

This is another part that errors, it's essentially the same but does it for the left picture box.

```
 Bitmap copy;
            lock (ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button)
           {
                copy = new Bitmap(ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button);
                pictureBox_leftConnectivity.Image = new Bitmap(ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button); // making a copy so we don't get into access problems
               // pictureBox_left = ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button;

            }

                pictureBox_left = copy;
```

My question is how do i fix this. What i think is happening is that in certain occasions my pictureBox_rightconnectivity.Image and pictureBox_leftconnectivity.Image are still being accessed by another thread. Where as another thread comes in and then tries to set that image. I was wondering how would i fix this? As you can see my initial attempt was to try to copy the image in the Bitmap copy object. and then use that to set the pictureBox_left and pictureBox_right. But i found this still threw the object is in use elsewhere error.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple problems with your code.

First, it's not permitted to access controls (like `PictureBox`) from a thread other than the thread on which they were created (hopefully the GUI thread).  So getting/setting `pictureBox_rightConnectivity.Image` from multiple threads is illegal, even if you're using locks.

Also, locking doesn't do any good unless you lock on the same object every time.  In your first code block, you're locking on `lockObject`.  In the second code block, you're locking on `ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button`.  Are these the same object?  If not, you don't get the "mutually exclusive" effect because there's nothing keeping one thread from obtaining the lock on `lockObject` while another holds the lock on `ArduinoUno_v1.Properties.Resources.on_button`.

These are just a couple things I see immediately.  There are probably other threading bugs.  In general, threading is something you should only do if you're sure (based on careful study) that you know what you're doing, because if you are at all unsure, you probably have bugs, and they're often bugs that are hard to reproduce and track down.